# htaccess - using password OR ip whitelist

Tags: .htaccess

So I want to restrict access to a url.  Now if they are coming from a given IP address then they shouldn't be prompted for a password.  If they are not coming from a givin IP address then they should be prompted for a password.

so a either or of:

```
AuthUserFile /some/path/.htpasswd
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

and:

```
order deny,allow

deny from all
allow from x.x.x.x
```

Answer (score 65):

You can use the Apache ["Satisfy"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy) directive.

Here is an example of using it :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthUserFile /some/path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy any
```

Access without password is only allowed from 127.0.0.1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 this is exactly what I do. Moreover, if you want to disable checks in some directory (e.g. some public/), just place in subdir's `.htaccess`:

Comment: `Allow from all` and `Satisfy any`

Answer (score 11):

With Apache 2.4 [`Satisfy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#satisfy) is still available, but [deprecated](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html)

> **Note**
>
> The directives provided by mod_access_compat have been deprecated by mod_authz_host. *Mixing old directives like Order, Allow or Deny with new ones like Require is technically possible but discouraged.* This module was created to support configurations containing only old directives to facilitate the 2.4 upgrade. Please check the upgrading guide for more information.

---

In your case `Allow from 1.2.3.4` is replaced by [`Require ip 1.2.3.4`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

Combining several `Require`s (like `Require valid-user` and `Require ip`) can be done by [Authorization Containers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#logic). So saying the client must either provide a password or come from a specific IP address, would be done by surrounding the directives with [`RequireAny`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireany), e.g.

```
<RequireAny>
    Require valid-user
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
</RequireAny>
```

Although, this is a special case as described at the end of [`Require`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

> When multiple Require directives are used in a single configuration section and are not contained in another authorization directive like `<RequireAll>`, *they are implicitly contained within a `<RequireAny>` directive.* Thus the first one to authorize a user authorizes the entire request, and subsequent Require directives are ignored.

In other words, `RequireAny` is optional here, and you can just list

```
Require valid-user
Require ip 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: So can you show a version of this that looks for a valid IP and if not asks for password, with location to htpasswd

Comment: @drooh I haven't tested, but maybe putting the `Require ip` first might do the trick. If it doesn't, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This workes perfect for me:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "myserver publicname"
AuthUserFile "/myserverpath/.htpasswds/public/passwd"
require ip 100.12.255.233
require valid-user
```

Note:
Just placed 'require ip' with 'my example ip' before 'require valid-user' and it does the trick. I can log in from my ip without password requested, but if I access from other locations or my mobile devices I need the password.

To set 'Satisfy any' was NOT GOOD FOR ME (!), because it disabled other .htaccess settings in lower hierarchy of my app and made my site insecure.